# Instagram Profile UIView structure

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to create an Instragram profile page-like view in iOS swift, but I don't know what and how you should go about making one! So, I'm guess you should use `UIScrollView` in the `ProfileViewController`, and embed `UICollectionView` for the pictures. But, isn't `UICollectionView` itself a subclass of `UIScrollView`? As far as I know, overlapping two `scrollView` is not a good practice.. Any recommendation? I want to have a profile picture on the top with name and caption right underneath the profile picture. And, a collection of pictures(column: 3) on the lower portion of the `ViewController`. Number of pictures are variable, so I need the `ViewController` scrollable.

Comment: Use only one collection view. Make multiple sections and use custom cells for various components of the screen. If you want to explore iOS too then it's not a bad idea to ho with a custom layout for your collection view.

Comment: So, do you mean that I should consider the profile details as one huge cell and make the photo cells smaller using constraints?

Comment: If you go with the flow layout then yes, that would be a better approach to do this. If you opt for custom layout then you'll have more liberty to layout your cells (including the huge profile cell). But like you said yourself, it's a bad idea to use a scrollview inside a scrollview specially when they both will be scrolling in the same direction.